# How to add folder from public_html to GitHub repository?

Tags: php, git, github

I made a GitHub repository for my PHP project. All files are located in `/home/nikola/public_html/todo/`. However, I don't know how to add it. First time I made it by typing this:

```
git add ~/public_html/todo
```

This time, it just doesn't work. When I try to do: `git add ~/public_html/todo` and type git status it says that one file is not yet commited (todo) but that's directory with files and directories in it! I can't find solution. I have cloned repository normal in `/home/nikola/todo` and tried to do this.

Comment: What is the exact wording of `git status` output message?

Comment: Typically I have had to do a pull request before doing the initial push.

Comment: GIT is a wonderful tool, but you do have to learn how to use it. [R.T.M](https://git-scm.com/documentation)

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov It says this: 
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

 modified:   ../../todo (untracked content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have something wrong with your github repository layout. The files that you want to add to your repository must be within the repository source tree.

The way I understand it, your git repo is in `~/todo` and you want to add files from `~/public_html/todo`, but this is not how git works. Copy your files into `~/todo` (`cp -r ~/public_html/todo/* ~/todo/`) and try again.

Comment: It doesn't help... gives the same error. Also, when I try to commit: `On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
 modified:   ../../todo (untracked content)
`

Comment: Omg, how stupid from me... I ran this from `~/public_html/todo` whole time :O Thanks for the help man!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! However, it is worrisome that you got response from git, you might have a random repository initiated in your home folder :)

Answer (score 0):

`git add` and `git commit` are two different commands. Simply typing `git add filename.ext` only tracks the files and makes them ready to be committed.

If you are looking for the files to be shown in your remote repository, you need to `git commit` the tracked files, and then `git push` them to the remote repo.

Git has an [interactive learning tool](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) that can help you learn and understand Git. I recommend checking it out until you are comfortable using the version control software.

Comment: I know that `git add` and `git commit` are different. But `git add` command doesnt track file in my case (check my comment on RiggsFolly's answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/nikola/public_html/todo/
```

If you have not already initialised a repo start with

```
git init
```

To add all files in this and any subfolders

```
git add .
git commit
```

Comment: Now, it says this:

On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

 modified:   ../../todo (untracked content)